# ImageView/View convert to mp4 as animation

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to save android ImageView/View to animation as mp4?

Something like imageView.getDrawichCache() but i need it as animation not as bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

If someone need this. It can be done by taking a few bitmaps and then use ffmpeg for android or jcodec to convert bitmaps(frames) into to mp4.